# How do I save a file with FMT extension?

Tags: sql-server

I need to save this text in a .FMT file. What do I use to save/make a file with such extension?
Reference [here](https://lite.ip2location.com/database-ip-country-region-city-latitude-longitude-zipcode-timezone). All the references I have found is to make an FMT from a table not from a file.

```
11.0
11
1 SQLCHAR 0 1 "\"" 0 first_double_quote  Latin1_General_CI_AI
2 SQLCHAR 0 20 "\",\"" 1 ip_from ""
3 SQLCHAR 0 20 "\",\"" 2 ip_to ""
4 SQLCHAR 0 2 "\",\"" 3 country_code Latin1_General_CI_AI
5 SQLCHAR 0 64 "\",\"" 4 country_name Latin1_General_CI_AI
6 SQLCHAR 0 128 "\",\"" 5 region_name Latin1_General_CI_AI
7 SQLCHAR 0 128 "\",\"" 6 city_name Latin1_General_CI_AI
8 SQLCHAR 0 20 "\",\"" 7 latitude ""
9 SQLCHAR 0 20 "\",\"" 8 longitude ""
10 SQLCHAR 0 30 "\",\"" 9 zip_code Latin1_General_CI_AI
11 SQLCHAR 0 8 "\"\r\n" 10 time_zone Latin1_General_CI_AI
```

Comment: You want to save it automatically from SQL Server?  I assume that is right otherwise you can copy/paste into notepad and then save as .FMT..!If so you can use XP_CMDSHELL and bcp.

Comment: @n34_panda Thanks. I know I can rename it as FMT but I have no idea if there is any implication in the formatting of the file content.

Comment: The last time I did this I don't think it did for me.  I've done it both ways but not recently...I take it you've read: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191516.aspx  Some more info: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178129.aspx  which sql server are you using?